# How to send extra Data and have it one after another by clicking a button

Tags: android, android-intent

for example when I click `but1` the `textview1` on the other activity must change,when I click `but2` the `textview2` must change etc.In my code when I click 3 buttons(one after another) after clicking the first one all  three `textviews` are being filled with the information that should be in first `textview.`
this is my first Activity:

```
    buttonvis1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    buttonvis2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    buttonvis2.setVisibility(Button.GONE);
    buttonvis1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Ostanovki.class);
            intent.putExtra("in1",input_in.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("out1", input_out.getText().toString());
            buttonvis2.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);
            //startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
    buttonvis3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    buttonvis3.setVisibility(Button.GONE);
    buttonvis2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Ostanovki.class);
            intent.putExtra("in2",input_in.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("out2", input_out.getText().toString());
            buttonvis3.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    buttonvis3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Ostanovki.class);
            intent.putExtra("in3",input_in.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("out3", input_out.getText().toString());
            //startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

and this is the second:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ostanovki);
    txtOst1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtost1);
    txtOst2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtost2);
    txtOst3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtost3);


    input1 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("in1");
    output1 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("out1");
    txtOst1.setText("В маршрутку зашло " +input1 +"а вышло " +output1);


    input2 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("in2");      
    output2 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("out2");
    txtOst2.setText("В маршрутку зашло " +input2 +"а вышло " +output2);


    input3 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("in3");      
    output3 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("out3");
    txtOst3.setText("В маршрутку зашло " +input3 +"а вышло " +output3);
```

I am a beginer,so don't be angry if I've written fool things.Thanks;)

Comment: why you comment `startActivity(intent);` in button 1 and button 3? how can go to next activity after clicked that?

Comment: I don't want to go to the next activity after clicking first button,I want to save all information in second activity and only after clicking third button I want the activity to be shown with information after clicking all the buttons.I commented them to check out if my prog works right or no.

Comment: I really don't understand what you want to do. you want after clicking all button text shown in next activity? so what is the problem?

Comment: I have 3 buttons. After clicking the first I want the text that must appear after clicking it to be just saved in the textview1,not shown but I don't want to switch to the activity i just want the text to be written there,so that I could watch it later after clicking all the buttons.After clicking the last button I want to go to that activity and watch the full list where there is the information.

Comment: I think you need to use SharedPreference in this case. It is more simple. Look at my answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading your comments I think using  SharedPreferences will make your task more easier:

Save your data

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("any_prefname", MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor editor = pref.edit();
editor.putString("in1",input_in.getText().toString() );
editor.putString("out1",input_out.getText().toString() );
editor.commit();
```

And then in the second activity retrieve your data as follows:,

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("any_prefname", MODE_PRIVATE);
    input1 = pref.getString("in1", "defaultString");
    output1 = pref.getString("out1", "defaultString");
    txtOst1.setText("В маршрутку зашло " +input1 +"а вышло " +output1);
```

Comment: When I try to retrieve my data there's an error saying: The method getString(String, String) in the type SharedPreferences is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Comment: Glad it helped! Yeah I omitted the default value. Thanks for pointing i t out.

Answer (score 0):

sorry its my mistake, now Receive it like this with bundle object:

In activity2, in onCreate(), you can get the String message by retrieving a bundle (which contains all the messages sent by the calling activity) and call getString on it :

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String message = bundle.getString("message");
```

Comment: dont forget to check for null

Comment: when I receive like this an error comes out: The method getExtras() is undefined for the type Bundle

Comment: sorry it was my mistake. Now see my answer @user3024751

Answer (score 0):

if I understand your problem you have 3 button that you want after clicking all of them see value in another activity, so you must put all three value into intent.use following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Ostanovki.class);

buttonvis1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
buttonvis2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
buttonvis2.setVisibility(Button.GONE);
buttonvis1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){

        intent.putExtra("in1",input_in.getText().toString());
        intent.putExtra("out1", input_out.getText().toString());
        buttonvis2.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);
        //startActivity(intent);

    }
});
buttonvis3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
buttonvis3.setVisibility(Button.GONE);
buttonvis2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        intent.putExtra("in2",input_in.getText().toString());
        intent.putExtra("out2", input_out.getText().toString());
        buttonvis3.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
buttonvis3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        intent.putExtra("in3",input_in.getText().toString());
        intent.putExtra("out3", input_out.getText().toString());
        //startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

and in second activity you must get data so use following code:

```
   Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
   String in1= bundle.getString("in1");
   String out1= bundle.getString("out1");

   String in2= bundle.getString("in2");
   String out2= bundle.getString("out2");

   String in3= bundle.getString("in3");
   String out3= bundle.getString("out3");
```